# What's the fastest way to decode a bytes object in Python?

Tags: python, utf-8

I'm decoding a large number of small utf-8 strings.

What would be the fastest way to decode?

Comment: fastest to code? fastest to run? Also please provide some sample input and expected output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by fastest you mean fastest to run, the normal `decode()` method of bytes should do the trick.

```
py -m timeit "b'test'.decode('utf8')"
1000000 loops, best of 5: 215 nsec per loop

py -m timeit "str(b'test', 'utf8')"
1000000 loops, best of 5: 339 nsec per loop
```

If you're interested about the difference, I'm guessing it's because `str()` goes through the instance creation mechanism twice. `str()` starts instantiating a new string, thus incurs overhead, reaches `__new__` and then goes to `PyUnicode_FromEncodedObject`.

`bytes.decode()` however goes straight to the same `PyUnicode_FromEncodedObject`, without doing any operation beforehand.

Comment: @snakecharmerb `str()` starts to create an instance (and incurs overhead), reaches `__new__` and then goes to `PyUnicode_FromEncodedObject`, while `bytes.decode()` goes straight to `PyUnicode_FromEncodedObject`. I've updated my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Thank you very much! How do I get to the relevant Python source code?

Comment: @SeanChambers1 Python's source code is hosted on GitHub. The relevant code for bytes is [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/488512bf4953d856fcb049a05060a450af52fcdc/Objects/bytesobject.c#L2334)